# Where should I add my add_action(init so I can use wp_set_object_terms?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin that parses a CSV and adds relationships between posts and post categories. When I use `wp_set_object_terms` to add the relationship I'm getting an error.

I found some information about adding my function to init to make taxonomy available to the function but that hasn't panned out. I may be adding it the wrong place. I also tried just using

`INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order) VALUES (".$locationID.",".$catsID.",0)`

but that generates the same error.

In my function I have

```
$addTermTaxonomy = wp_set_object_terms(intval($locationID), intval($catsID), true);

if (is_wp_error($addTermTaxonomy)){
    echo"<span style='color:red'>----THERE WAS AN ERROR. THIS COULD NOT BE SET.</span><br/>";
    $error_string = $addTermTaxonomy->get_error_message();
    echo"<span style='color:red'>----".$error_string."</span><br/><br/>";

}else{
    echo "<span style='color:green'>--".$beer." has been added to this location</span><br/><br/>"; 
}
```

`$error_string` always comes out as Invalid taxonomy. Where should I be adding my `add_action('init', 'FUNCTION _NAME');` to allow me to use `wp_set_object_terms`?

Comment: What "error" exactly?

Comment: @cabrerahector `$addTermTaxonomy->get_error_message(); ` comes out as Invalid Taxonomy

Comment: Hi, are you sure the terms already exist? If they don't you'll get the error you mention.

You could check with `term_exists()`, if the Terms does not exist you may need to create them first.

Comment: What Lucas said. [The `wp_set_object_terms()` function returns a `WP_Error` object if the taxonomy doesn't exist](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms#Returns) so double check your code: the third parameter should be an actual taxonomy, you're passing a boolean (`true`).

Comment: @cabrerahector That's the ticket. I was missing the taxonomy in my call. The `true` is to append the information rather than replacing. Once I did my call correctly it started working. Thanks.